# Codeigniter db->where() not working in foreach loop

Tags: codeigniter

On my view I need to be able to get the hidden banner_image_id and use that in my `$this->db->where('banner_image_id', $id)` on my model function

When I update the image. It does not update to the correct row. Instead it update all rows with the same filename.

**Question:** On my model how can I make sure that my `$this->db->where('banner_image_id', $id)` updates correct rows.

I have done a vardump($id) and result is `string(2) "63"` which is correct but still updates every row the same. I tried update_batch also no luck.

**Model Function**

```
public function edit_banner_image($file_name) {
    $banner_image_id = $this->input->post('banner_image_id');

    if (isset($banner_image_id)) {
        foreach ($banner_image_id as $id) { 
            //var_dump($id);
            //exit;
            $data = array('banner_id' => $this->uri->segment(4),'banner_image' => $file_name);

            $this->db->where('banner_image_id', $id);

            //$this->db->where_in('banner_image_id', $id); // Tried No Luck
            //$this->db->or_where_in('banner_image_id', $id); // Tried No Luck

            $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'banner_img', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

**View Table**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($banner_images as $img) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $img['banner_image_id'];?>
                <input type="hidden" name="banner_image_id[]" value="<?php echo $img['banner_image_id'];?>">
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="file" name="banner_image[]" multiple size="20">
           </td>
           <td>
               <img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'uploads/' . $img['banner_image'];?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="banner_image" value="<?php echo $img['banner_image'];?>">
           </td>
       </tr>
       <?php }?>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate the id numbers in foreach loop and pass it where function at once.

Assuming that your id numbers are `array(1,2,5,6)`.

```
public function edit_banner_image($file_name) {
    $banner_image_id = $this->input->post('banner_image_id');

    if (isset($banner_image_id)) {

        $bid = 'IN(';
        foreach ($banner_image_id as $id) { 
            $bid .= $id . ',';
        }

        $bid = substr($bid, 0, -1) . ')'; //remove last comma and add closing paranthesis.
        //The content of the variable $bid would be like
        //IN(1,2,5,6)

        $data = array('banner_id' => $this->uri->segment(4),'banner_image' => $file_name);

        $this->db->where('banner_image_id', $id);
        $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'banner_img', $data);

    }
}
```

**Another Suggestion:**

Convert `$banner_image_id` to a normal array in case of it is an associative array.

```
public function edit_banner_image($file_name) {
    $banner_image_id = $this->input->post('banner_image_id'); 
    $bid = array();

    if (isset($banner_image_id)) {
        foreach ($banner_image_id as $id) { 
            $bid[] = $id;
        }

        $data = array('banner_id' => $this->uri->segment(4),
                      'banner_image' => $file_name);

        $this->db->where_in('banner_image_id', $bid);
        $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'banner_img', $data);    
    }
}
```

I suggest you to make convertion in the **controller** section, not in model. The lines ending with `//` should be in the controller. You can easily pass `$bid` to  `edit_banner_image($file_name, $bid)` function then.

```
public function edit_banner_image($file_name, $bid) {
    $banner_image_id = $this->input->post('banner_image_id'); //
    $bid = array();//

    if (isset($banner_image_id)) {//
        foreach ($banner_image_id as $id) { //
            $bid[] = $id;//
        }

        $data = array('banner_id' => $this->uri->segment(4),
                      'banner_image' => $file_name);

        $this->db->where_in('banner_image_id', $bid);
        $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'banner_img', $data);    
    }
}
```

Thus, you will have more readable code.